# Flutter web laggy after running

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

i have built a flutter web app and used firebase to deploy, when i launch the app for a while (about 30s) it lags and freezes, not showing any error message, anyone have any problem similar situation? How can I check them? i am using flutter version 2.10.4, dart version 2.16.2

Comment: Please share some code. It occurred if the memory leak. Some bad coding.

Comment: Flutter web load everything 1st then present on UI. It is normal behavior of flutter web, you can show loading/splash screen while loading data. The freezing issue you are talking might be the default splash screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by change flutter web render to html in the web/index.html:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    let useHtml = true
    if(useHtml) {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
    } else {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";
    }
</script>
```